# Pyrit install ends with abort after selecting

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation

Trying to install `pyrit` v0.5.0 the install ends with `Abort` after the install says `continue [Y/n]`.

The commands for v0.5.0 ends with abort.

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
python-is-python2 is already the newest version (2.7.17-4). 
python-is-python2 set to manually installed. 
The following additional packages will be installed: 
  ipython3 libexpat1-dev libpython2-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev python2.7-dev python3-backcall python3-decorator python3-ipython python3-ipython-genutils python3-jedi python3-parso python3-pickleshare python3-prompt-toolkit python3-pygments python3-traitlets python3-wcwidth 
Suggested packages: 
  libssl-doc python-ipython-doc python-pygments-doc ttf-bitstream-vera graphviz python3-matplotlib python3-pyx sox tcpreplay 
The following NEW packages will be installed: 
  ipython3 libexpat1-dev libpcap0.8-dev libpython2-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libssl-dev python2-dev python2.7-dev python3-backcall python3-decorator python3-ipython python3-ipython-genutils python3-jedi python3-parso python3-pickleshare python3-prompt-toolkit python3-pygments python3-scapy python3-traitlets python3-wcwidth zlib1g-dev 
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded. 
Need to get 8,591 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 44.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y Abort.
```

Testing for `pyrit` says it is not installed:

```
$ pyrit benchmark
pyrit: command not found
```

Comment: Question by Avishek Acharya Av "how install pyrit i was using linset when it asked to install it" on July 14 2021. Answered by N0rbert July 14 2021 is the solution to this question.